# Разбиение данных по сегментам

Tags: память

При сегментном представлении памяти, выделяют сегменты кода и сегменты данных. Например, если у меня есть код, выполняющий простую арифметическую операцию,`A = B + C` то будут ли переменные вместе с арифметической операцией храниться в одном сегменте или же они будут разбиты по разным сегментам? И имеет ли данное разбиение отношения к правам доступа на данный сегмент?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос: если переменные находятся в памяти, то они будут находиться в сегменте данных, а операции над ними в сегменте кода. Если же переменные являются регистрами (например, `eax`, `ebx`, `ecx` соответственно), то сегмент данных никак не задействован. А вот про права доступа не совсем понимаю вопрос.

Comment: Просто сегодня преподаватель на вопрос "Чем сегменты отличаются от страниц" (помимо того, что у страниц фиксированный размер) начал объяснять, что так как дескриптор сегмента имеет такую составляющую, как право доступа (read, write, execute), то следовательно и переменные и арифметические операции будут храниться в разных сегментах. Однако, как из разных сегментов получить тот же тривиальный код A = B + С - я не понял(

Comment: @Arius Тривиальный код A = B + C ты найдёшь в сегменте кода. А сами значения A, B, C находятся в сегменте данных. A = B + C в ассемблере будет выглядеть примерно так:
`mov eax, [B]
add eax,[C]
mov [A], eax`
Эти инструкции и будут храниться в сегменте кода. Физический адрес какой-то конкретной операции находится, как cs:ip, где cs - регистр сегмента кода.

Answer (score 0):

Современные ОС, такие как Windows и Linux на архитектуре x86 не используют сегментную организацию памяти. Все сегменты указывают на всю памяти.

Также точно древний формат .com в древней OS MS-DOS использовал один сегмент в 64кб, на который указывали все сегментные регистры.

И вообще в фон-Неймановской архитектуре (в отличии от Гарвардской) разделение на код и данные довольно условное.

Современные процессоры позволяют разделить код и данные по разным страницам памяти, выставив им разные разрешения. Многие современные компиляторы это разделение также поддерживают и используют.

Но никто не помешает написать вставку на ассемблере, и смешать данные и код в одну кучу.